# How can I eval code in JRuby, in a new context every time?

Tags: jruby

I want to allow evaluation of code in a shell-like app. At a press of a button, the code will be evaluated and a result will be showed to the user. I want to make it so that if he evaluates code again, everything defined in old evaluation will no longer exist. For example, imagine this is eval #1:

```
puts "Hello world"
user_variable1  = 10
$USER_VARIABLE2 = 20
```

I want that on eval #2, the values of `user_variable1` and `$USER_VARIABLE2` not to exist. This is why I'm thinking of using some kind of context on each run. However, I don't know where to look for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just run another (or the same script) in another process using some way of executing the commands. Something like

```
system('myscript.rb')
```

or

```
`myscript.rb`
```

This will ensure that any variables are cleared, however, the environment variables will of course be the same. Since ruby 1.9 you can reset them too, though. Like so:

```
system('myscript.rb', :unsetenv_others => true)
```

If you want something very close to the `eval()` function, you could create an `eval.rb`, that will just evaluate the first parameter and then define an `evalExt` function:

eval.rb:

```
eval(ARGV[0])
```

And then in your other script:
    def evalExt(script)
       system("eval.rb \"#{script}\"", :unsetenv_others => true)
    end

```
evalExt('puts "test"')
evalExt('puts "test1"')
```

In case of JRuby you should be able to invoke another ruby engine as easily, by calling Java code from JRuby and then using the `ScriptEngineManager` as described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRuby#JRuby_calling_Java):

```
require 'java'

mgr = ScriptEngineManager.new();
rbEngine = mgr.getEngineByExtension("rb");

def evalExt(script)
   rbEngine.eval(script);
end
```

Maybe you will have to ensure to reset the script context or bindings ([see this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/)).

All that said, maybe the easiest solution would be to just ensure that no global variables are set, then you do not have to seperate contexts at all.

Comment: Ok, but what if I'm running this from a self contained JRuby jar? I won't have Ruby in path, and invoking another JRuby will be much too slow.